# Why was this question closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

A few days ago, I posted a question on SF about [enabling PHP for all virtual hosts in nginx without having to duplicate configuration blocks](https://serverfault.com/questions/456637/nginx-enable-php-for-all-hosts).

However, the question was closed soon after as `off-topic`. I have looked at the FAQ about the type of questions that can be asked here and it seems to be somewhat vague.

My question was about servers, software and operations and it was not about something used in a home-setting, licensing or product recommendations.

At the same time, there are also loads of nginx configuration questions:

- [Can Nginx handle php (or similar fcgi) requests inside of an alias?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15031/can-nginx-handle-php-or-similar-fcgi-requests-inside-of-an-alias?rq=1)
- [Nginx and multiple wordpress instances with fastcgi under same domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/149638/nginx-and-multiple-wordpress-instances-with-fastcgi-under-same-domain?rq=1)

**Why was my question closed as off-topic?** I would like to know to prevent myself from posting off-topic questions in the future.

**Where would be a more appropriate place to post that question?**

Comment: Seems like a fine question to me - the only sin you committed was pasting your whole configuration file (which is a lesser sin, like betting on the superbowl).  We generally prefer only the *relevant* sections of the config, though if you're not sure what's "relevant" it's better to paste it all.  (And to be fair I looked at it for 5 minutes and couldn't figure out what to trim to tighten it up, so you probably posted about the minimum amount of information :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets start with: This is Server Fault. Not Super User. If you meant to post on Super User, we can migrate the question there.

I'm not sure why this was closed; but I'm thinking it's people getting overzealous with our shiny new `review` system. Especially since it got an answer, and there aren't any close comments.

My apologies on behalf of Server Fault for the inconvenience.

Comment: Great answer :) My apologies, I actually meant SF and not SU. :)